expo-go development app not communicating with flask API
Problem details
I am running an Android Expo Go app in development mode which appears to be available at these locations:

› Choose an app to open your project at
http://192.168.0.49:8081/_expo/loading › Metro waiting on
exp://192.168.0.49:8081 › Scan the QR code above with Expo Go
(Android) or the Camera app (iOS)
› Web is waiting on http://localhost:8081

I'm attempting to make the app communicate with a Flask backend API:
$ flask --app backend run
 * Serving Flask app 'backend'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000

If I directly check the IP of the mobile device I am running the Expo Go app on it says:

192.168.0.50

The IP of the machine I am running the flask server is:

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.49

But I am getting network errors when attempting to perform GET requests from the expo app to the Flask server:

ERROR  Test error: [TypeError: Network request failed]


Code snippets
My expo tsx code for performing a test API ping looks like this:
const testFetch = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://192.168.0.49:5000/test');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Test response data:', data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Test error:', error);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    testFetch();
}, []);

Which envokes the flask code:
@bp.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return jsonify({"message": "Test successful"}), 200

...and the flask app is setup to receive incoming requests using CORS:
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    from . import home
    app.register_blueprint(home.bp)

    return app


Things I have tried to fix/find the issue

I set the inbound and outbound traffic on port:5000 in Windows Defender Firewall
I have tried opening the Flask endpoints on my mobile phone in a browser. They do not load
I have tried setting the flask app to listen on all ports: flask --app backend run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000 --debug
I have tried all combinations of https://localhost:5000 and actual IP addresses in the fetch request
I have tried running the Flask server and the Expo Go app on a different network (my mobile data)
Directly (and successfully) pinging the flask API using curl in WSL: curl http://192.168.0.49:5000/fetchprogram?programID=test_program
I tried switching out the endpoint from my flask app to a public API endpoint which worked ('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')


It turns out this was an issue whereby I was running the flask server from inside WSL2 and it doesn't share a direct IP address communication pathway with the Windows localhost IP.
This was solved by following the simple instructions found in this post and article: https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/zl57wt/cant_connect_or_ping_wsl_from_host/
